# Проблема с preg_replace

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

После переноса сайта на другой хостинг появилась проблема с регулярками (до этого таких проблем не было, по этому соотношу сие событие с хостингом).
Кароче говоря, есть регулярка     `

```
$country = preg_replace('/[^А-Яа-яA-Za-z ]/', '', $_POST['country']);
```

К примеру, если вводится страна "Россия", то в БД записывается как Ро??ия, аналогично и с другими странами, причем буквы каждый раз разные заменяются на "?". Если написать регулярку таким образом, то всё отображается нормально:    `

```
$country = preg_replace('/[^АБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя]/', '', $_POST['country']);
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: О_о спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте модификатор u для регулярного выражения.

Answer (score 0):

знаки вопросов в ромбиках черных? если да то проблемы в кодировке

Comment: нет, в том то и дело, раньше были в ромбиках, пересохранил файл с кодировкой UTF-8 без BOM, стало всё нормально

Comment: $country = preg_replace('/[^А-Яа-яA-Za-z ]/u', '', $_POST['country']);

Попробуйте с параметром /u

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php