# Проблемы с кириллицей в регулярных выражениях на PHP (preg_replace, preg_match)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, кириллица

Нужно заменить на тоже самое, но с добавками. На английском работает, с русским проблема (не меняет). тестировал [здесь](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/33fbd536ea273bf49fffa579ca195013fcddce5b) .  Пробовал с mb_ereg_replace, но тоже не получилось....

```
$text = "Слово слоВо Test tesT";

$word = 'слово';


$text = preg_replace('/(' . $word . ')/i', '<b>\\1</b>', $text);

$word = 'test';
$text = preg_replace('/(' . $word . ')/i', '<i>\\1</i>', $text);

echo $text;
```

Comment: Модификатор `u` добавьте, чтобы с UTF-8 работало корректно.

Comment: @Visman спасибо, как то я этот модификатор раньше нигде не видел...

Comment: Тут http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php можете почитать о модификаторах в php.

Comment: @Visman спасибо, я эту страницу нашёл после вашего коммента, до этого я пользовался справочниками, а в них этот модификатор к сожалению не показан...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [preg\_match некорректно обрабатывает кириллицу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/263332/preg-match-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83) или [Проблема с preg_replace](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/201340/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-preg-replace/201342#201342).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - ответ оказался таким же, но когда возникает вопрос использования  preg_replace на многобайтовых кодировках, человек чаще будет искать всё-таки preg_replace и mb_ereg_replace, чем preg_match и не находя ответа, будет снова создавать подобные темы...

Comment: Вы думаете, что вопрос с таким заголовком как *регулярные выражения, русский шрифт. Заменить на тоже самое, но с добавками* поможет остальным? Кто будет искать *русский шрифт с добавками*? А вот *Проблемы с кириллицей в регулярных выражениях на PHP* или нечто подобное уже было бы лучше.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew подправил название и добавил решение у вопрос

Comment: Вообще-то, решение надо опубликовать как ответ. А я бы удалил пост.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение: нужно использовать модификатор "u" :

```
'/(' . $word . ')/iu'
```